# PHP each() function is deprecated

Tags: php

I'm trying to update my code with little success.

```
  <?php
  reset($gb_options);
  while (list(, $gb_opts) = each($gb_options)) {
  echo('          <option value="'.$gb_opts.'">'.$gb_opts.'</option>'."\n"); 
 } 
?>
```

Comment: Use [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
  reset($gb_options);

  foreach ($gb_options as $option) {
    echo('          <option value="' . $option[1] . '">' . $option[1] . '</option>'."\n"); 
  }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Unfortunately if I use your suggestion I lose the drop down options. It's a contact form here -  https://www.voip4eu dotcom/contact.php